# How can I read every field as string in xlwings?

Tags: python, converters, type-conversion, xlwings

I have an exelfile that I want to convert but the default type for numbers is float. How can I change it so xlwings explicitly uses strings and not numbers?

This is how I read the value of a field:
`xw.Range(sheet, fieldname ).value`

The problem is that numbers like `40` get converted to `40.0` if I create a string from that. I strip it with: `str(xw.Range(sheetFronius, fieldname ).value).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` but that is not very helpful and leads to errors because sometimes the same field can contain both a number and a string. (Not at the same time, the value is chosen from a list)

Answer (score 3):

With xlwings if no options are set during reading/writing operations single cells are read in as 'floats'. Also, by default cells with numbers are read as 'floats'. I scoured the docs, but don't think you can convert a cell that has numbers to a 'string' via xlwings outright. Fortunately all is not lost...

You could read in the cells as 'int' with xlwings and then convert the 'int' to 'string' in Python. The way to do that is as follows:

```
xw.Range(sheet, fieldname).options(numbers=int).value
```

And finally, you can read in your data this way (by packing the string conversion into the options upfront):

```
xw.Range(sheet, fieldname).options(numbers=lambda x: str(int(x))).value
```

Then you would just convert that to string in Python in the usual way.

Good luck!

Comment: You can pack the string conversion into the options: `xw.Range(sheet, fieldname).options(numbers=lambda x: str(int(x))).value`

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I can't use it that way because there can also be a string in that field.

Comment: @simonides the lambda expression is only applied on numbers, strings are left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

In my case conclusion was, just adding one row to the last row of raw data.

Write any text in the column you want to change to str, save, load, and then delete the last line.